# Why am I unable to use CreateWICTextureFromFileEx after shutting down SDL

Tags: c++, sdl, directx-12, directxtk

I am trying to shutdown my DX12 renderer, and restart it within the same process.

Said application is heavily based on the microsoft MiniEngine example code, now with some modification to allow re-initialisation of global variables. I am using SDL for window and event management.

The last stumbling block for a clean shutdown and re-initialisation, it appears, is the loading of textures in a texture manager class, which in turn uses the `DirectXTK12` code to load textures, via `CreateWICTextureFromFileEx` for `.png` files.

To summarise what I'm trying to do:

- start up application
- initialise rendering into SDL window
- render in rendering loop
- shut down all rendering and window handling (remove all resources, release device handle) - calls `SDL_Quit`
- re-initialise rendering into new SDL window (get new device handle, etc)
- render in rendering loop

The texture management class is shut down as part of the rendering shutdown, removing all traces of textures and their handles to resources etc.

As part of the rendering re-initialisation, the default textures are created via `CreateWICTextureFromFileEx`. (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Src/WICTextureLoader.cpp)) and crash when trying to do this.

EDIT: since first posting, I can say that this crashing starts directly after calling `SDL_Quit()` (and persists after the call to restart with `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)`)

I am now fairly confident it's an issue with this area specifically rather than some other part of the renderer that isn't being re-initialised correctly, since I can force it to use `.DDS` textures instead of `.png`s, and the system fires up again nicely. In this case it uses `DDSTextureLoader` without any (obvious) problems.

I've added the source to my project and can see the crash is occurring when trying to do this:

```
ComPtr<IWICBitmapDecoder> decoder;
    HRESULT hr = pWIC->CreateDecoderFromFilename(fileName,
        nullptr,
        GENERIC_READ,
        WICDecodeMetadataCacheOnDemand,
        decoder.GetAddressOf());
```

The failure reported is

```
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
pWIC->**** was 0x7FFAC0B0C610.
```

`pWIC` here is obtained via `_GetWIC()` which is using a singleton initialisation:

```
IWICImagingFactory2* _GetWIC() noexcept
    {
        static INIT_ONCE s_initOnce = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;

        IWICImagingFactory2* factory = nullptr;
        if (!InitOnceExecuteOnce(
            &s_initOnce,
            InitializeWICFactory,
            nullptr,
            reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&factory)))
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

        return factory;
    }
```

Since first posting, I can now say that this crashing starts directly after calling `SDL_Quit()`. I have test code that starts the graphics up enough to get a device and get a texture, which will complete successfully at any point until `SDL_Quit`.
Re-initialising SDL with `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` doesn't help.

I also note that the `WICTextureLoader` comments state "Assumes application has already called CoInitializeEx". Is this an area that `SDL_Quit` could be messing with?

Comment: Wild guess, but afaik, `WICTextureLoader` needs `CoInitialize` to be called before usage.
Maybe `SDL_Quit` calls `CoUninitialize`?

Comment: so it does indeed - there must be something other than SDL_Init I need to call to get it to call CoInitialize again

Comment: I am not sure though if the factory initialized in `_GetWIC` is going to still be valid after `CoUninitialize`?

Comment: CoInitialize has an internal count, try calling it more than once at startup to see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post an answer here but will remove it if @ChuckWalbourn wants to post his own.
This was due to letting SDL call `CoInitialize` for me. 
When it cleaned up through `SDL_Quit`, it called `CoUninitialize` which then (presumably) invalidated the `IWICImagingFactory2` set up by `WICTextureLoader` .
 By adding a call to `CoInitialize` in my rendering startup, the internal count in `CoInitialize` keeps the `IWICImagingFactory2` alive and all is well.